# NVDA is triggering the wrong button press script for my menu

Tags: javascript, accessibility, nvda

The link below contains my expansion of the pull-out menu design originally conceived by Marcy Sutton. My desired effect was to create a navigation menu that included sub-menus. In the context of screen readers, the elements in this menu would be disabled until someone pushed the button to open the desired information.

Having tested this menu on Firefox, Chrome, and IE, the menu behaves as expected. When running a popular screen reader named NVDA, however, the wrong buttons seem to fire off. Here are the steps I take to reproduce the bug:

1. Using tab and spacebar, I open the Portfolio submenu. This highlights the Website 1 link.
2. Using shift and tab, I navigate backward to the [X] Menu ("close the main menu") button. As I do this, the portfolio button automatically closes again. Normal behavior so far.
3. Attempting to re-open the portfolio button at this point, however, results in either a) the main navigation menu button firing its event, so the menu closes, or b) the menu closes because, somehow the focus jumps to the heading (which is a link).

Codepen: https://codepen.io/nitronova/pen/qPbpMO

```
 function initApp()
 { // Bind actions to functions.
  navButton.addEventListener( "click", handleNavButtonClick, false );
  conWrap.addEventListener( "click", handleOutMenuClick, false );
  document.body.addEventListener( "keyup", handleKeyup, false ) /* navMenu. */
  for( var i = 0; i < navButtons.length; i++ ) 
  {
   navButtons[i].addEventListener( "click", handleSubMenuButtonClick, false );
   console.log('closing submenus init');
   closeSubMenu(navButtons[i]);
  }
  console.log('closing the nav menu init');
  closeNavMenu();
 }
```

Note here: The main navigation button ("navButton") gets its own function called handleNavButtonClick, while submenus ("navButtons") get handleSubMenuButtonClick. Two totally separate functions. The problem is not with the functions in the script, but with how NVDA is causing the wrong functions (or event triggers) to fire.

There are no error messages; the behavior path is the problem. I have screenshots that demonstrate that the wrong events are firing when NVDA is running. https://i.stack.imgur.com/yfFFD.jpg

Honestly, I'm still a novice with JavaScript. Does anyone here have any explanation for this? Is there something I am doing wrong?

Comment: Sorry I'm not into JS, so just a thought: What is happening when clicking (or activating) the X-button (close) in your script? Where will the focus go next? Maybe you have to define in your script the next focus element, that will be selected after closing the submenu?

Comment: The close button is a button element, so clicking it changes the focus to the button. As for clicking the submenu element, I do in fact specify that when you're opening it that the focus should shift to the first link in the submenu.

Comment: Yes thats what I ment. The focus stays at first on the close button. But the button itself is removed/hidden after clicking it, so the focus jumps to an undefined following element I guess. Thats what I ment, maybe you have to define in your script the next focus element that is focused after clicking the close button...

Comment: Sorry. Adding focus to the main menu button when you click close does not help with the bug involving the portfolio button. But when I added a .focus() to the portfolio button when it closes, it started going absolutely nuts. It's like NVDA and .focus() fight with each other or something.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a bug in NVDA, Here is the summary of the root cause of this problem.

https://github.com/nvaccess/nvda/issues/8326